# Best educational tests (exams) system - web based

Tags: web-development, web-services, educational

I'm in charge of 'computerize' different procedures in a local high-school center. Last week I was addressed by a teacher who wanted to 'take his foreign language book' to a web level. She wrote and designed the book herself and now owes a very nice PDF document.

After some discussion she now would like the following to have the PDF including audio and video with links to online resources (easy). On top of it  she'd like

- **the ability to design tests (exams) in different flavours, such as fill in the blank, true/false, free writing... and publish them online (web pages)**
- **where she could choose whether tests are auto-evaluated (by the student) or evaluated by her**
- **and ideally she could be able to keep track of students progress**.
- **Besides, there should be access control (user/password that she may reset herself)**

I doubt whether there's any web service offering it that we could hire or there's any API or CMS (such as Drupal) where I could deploy it.

I'm sure this procedure for education may be deployed in different places but couldn't find any close solution yet.

Any tip, also of forums about development for education, is more than appreciated.

Thank you. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

To do something like this, there are many options to explore including using a CMS. They all give some of what you require (different question types, tracking results of students, access control) and more... Some examples include:

- [Moodle](https://moodle.org/) - a very popular learning management system.
- [Drupal Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) and its associated modules.

There are also many proprietary solutions out there too. My advice will be to start with one of the open source ones above, to get a feel for your requirements etc.

Comment: Ty! Moodle is... too much for 'a book + quizzes'. I'll give a look to Drupal Quiz as I'm used to work with Drupal. Anyway, I was after some more straightforward solution, most probably a commercial one that can fit the requirements. Thank you anyway.

Comment: About Drupal Quiz there's some objection: it is stuck in Drupal 7. Not that that version is YET unmaintained, but almost ( see https://www.drupal.org/docs/understanding-drupal/drupal-9-release-date-and-what-it-means/what-happens-to-drupal-7-now-that )

Comment: There is a version 6.x for drupal 8 & 9. You'll have to check if now fully converted and decide what is best for your case. I am still using quiz for drupal 7, and its been running for a few years. Will convert or use something else when necessary...

Comment: Ty ZZ. I tried one of the online demos and failed. I'll try to test it in local with v.6.
It's interesting to know someone making use of it. Have a nice day!

Comment: My advice will be to test the dev version locally as that's the most up to date https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz/releases/6.x-dev Also see issues queue and post question if necessary: https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/quiz?text=&status=Open&priorities=All&categories=All&version=any_6.&component=All

Comment: I am still interested in commercial hosted solutions, if any. It may be more convenient for my client and despite I'll make less money (I'm the developer) I won't have to keep in charge of future maintenance and updates. T.I.A.

Comment: You'll need to search for that. I don't know of any... Another open source one I came across is https://github.com/richwalm/nzarttrainer but not tried it yet.

Comment: Ty ZZ. I was not expecting you to do all my work :-D I'll give a look to the link you've just provided. Thank you very much for your help and attention. Have a nice day, week, month...