# Multiple Choice Questions (MCQ) test for students

Tags: pdf

I have to create an MCQ test for my students. I know I can use MS Word for that. I want to know if there is a free specialised tool for this.

Comment: Please add what platform and how you want students to run MCQ tests.

Answer (score 0):

Please see previous answers and discussion posted [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/77994/best-educational-tests-exams-system-web-based/78003#78003), suggesting solutions like [Moodle](https://moodle.org/) and [Drupal Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) . But this depends on whether you want the overhead of running full-blown systems. They both handle MCQ, and a lot more... Both can run on internet or intranet so that your students can log in and answer.

Also see [NZART Trainer](https://github.com/richwalm/nzarttrainer)